# Can diffusion current occur in conductors?

Tags: electrons, electric-current, semiconductor-physics, diffusion

The question is quite simple. Can diffusion current occur in conductors like they're found PN-junction semiconductors due to concentration gradient? I need to see a rigorous description. Is there any example or any possibility of diffusion taking place in a conductor?
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course diffusion currents (charge moving from higher concentration to lower
concentration) can occur in metals.  There are also contact potentials
(charge redistribution from metals with a high Fermi energy to those with 
a lower Fermi energy).   The
balance of these currents is temperature-sensitive, which gives us the property
known as the Seebeck effect, and useful devices called thermocouples.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just studying semiconductors, from a book by Streetman  and Banerjee, the book explains the diffusion process very clearly:

"When a bottle of perfume is opened in one corner of a closed room, the scent is soon detected throughout the room. If there's no convection or net motion of air, the scent spreads by diffusion. The diffusion is a natural result of the *random motion* of individual molecules... The process​ continues until the molecules are uniformly distributed in the room. It stops only when a given volume gain as many molecules as it loses in a given time. In other words, net diffusion will continue as long as gradients exist in the distribution of scented molecules."

So if you are asking about diffusion currents in conductors: suppose a conductor is heated on one side more than other side, then the molecules will undergo thermal motion and collisions with other molecules (due to energy gained while heating). This will continue as long as temperature gradient(s) exist in the conductor. I will say, thus, that diffusion can take place in conductors and many other things if there are such circumstances.